# IDE не может установить импорт Csv/Config/Decouple

Tags: python, django, pip

Проблема заключается в том, что встроенный дебагер ругается на эти строки.

```
from decouple import config, Csv
from unipath import Path
```

Я пытался установить через IDE, как рекомендовал сам дебагер, однако получаю ошибки.

```
Collecting decouple
  Using cached decouple-0.0.7.tar.gz (3.3 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'

ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 245, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
                ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 182, in _make_candidate_from_link
    base: Optional[BaseCandidate] = self._make_base_candidate_from_link(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 228, in _make_base_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 293, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 304, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 525, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 640, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 71, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 54, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._install_build_reqs(finder)
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 124, in _install_build_reqs
    build_reqs = self._get_build_requires_wheel()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\sdist.py", line 101, in _get_build_requires_wheel
    return backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 751, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return super().get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings=cs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_impl.py", line 166, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_impl.py", line 321, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pip._vendor.pyproject_hooks._impl.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\.virtualenvs\TattooFoundlerProject-1CIClaAs\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1304, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1318, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'


[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.3.2 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

После нескольких попыток я решил попробовать сделать тоже самое в PowerShell от админа. Там всё установилось, однако в самом IDE, даже после перезапуска остаеётся эта проблема.

Вот что показано в консоле повера.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> cd E:\TattooFoundlerProject\TattooFoundler
PS E:\TattooFoundlerProject\TattooFoundler> pip install decouple
Requirement already satisfied: decouple in c:\users\otterandfinek\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (0.0.7)
PS E:\TattooFoundlerProject\TattooFoundler> pip install unipath
Requirement already satisfied: unipath in c:\users\otterandfinek\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (1.1)
PS E:\TattooFoundlerProject\TattooFoundler> pip install setuptools
>>
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\otterandfinek\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (68.0.0)
PS E:\TattooFoundlerProject\TattooFoundler> pip cache purge
>>
Files removed: 246
PS E:\TattooFoundlerProject\TattooFoundler> pip install decouple
Requirement already satisfied: decouple in c:\users\otterandfinek\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (0.0.7)
PS E:\TattooFoundlerProject\TattooFoundler> pip install https://pypi.org/simple/decouple/0.5.0/decouple-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
>>
Collecting decouple==0.5.0
  ERROR: HTTP error 404 while getting https://pypi.org/simple/decouple/0.5.0/decouple-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install requirement decouple==0.5.0 from https://pypi.org/simple/decouple/0.5.0/decouple-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl because of HTTP error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/decouple/0.5.0/decouple-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl for URL https://pypi.org/simple/decouple/0.5.0/decouple-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Как видно, я пытался установить их вручную, чистил кеш и пытался переустановить, но это не дало никаких плодов, в чем может быть проблема?

Изначально я зациклился на этом из-за ошибка runserver.

Если необходимо - вот моя base.py ( ака setting.py)

```
import dj_database_url
from decouple import Csv, config
from unipath import Path


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# ==============================================================================
# CORE SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY", default="django-insecure$TattooFoundler.settings.local")

DEBUG = config("DEBUG", default=True, cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config("ALLOWED_HOSTS", default="127.0.0.1,localhost", cast=Csv())


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "TattooFoundler.apps.accounts",
    "TattooFoundler.apps.core",
]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

ROOT_URLCONF = "TattooFoundler.urls"

INTERNAL_IPS = ["127.0.0.1"]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "TattooFoundler.wsgi.application"


# ==============================================================================
# MIDDLEWARE SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]


# ==============================================================================
# TEMPLATES SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]


# ==============================================================================
# DATABASES SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

DATABASES = {
    "default": dj_database_url.config(
        default=config("DATABASE_URL", default="postgres://TattooFoundler:TattooFoundler@localhost:5432/TattooFoundler"),
        conn_max_age=600,
    )
}


# ==============================================================================
# AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# ==============================================================================
# I18N AND L10N SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

LANGUAGE_CODE = config("LANGUAGE_CODE", default="en-us")

TIME_ZONE = config("TIME_ZONE", default="UTC")

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [BASE_DIR / "locale"]


# ==============================================================================
# STATIC FILES SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR.parent.parent / "static"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
)


# ==============================================================================
# MEDIA FILES SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.parent.parent / "media"



# ==============================================================================
# THIRD-PARTY SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=True, cast=bool)
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST', default='localhost')
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT', default=25, cast=int)

# ==============================================================================
# FIRST-PARTY SETTINGS
# ==============================================================================

TattooFoundler_ENVIRONMENT = config("TattooFoundler_ENVIRONMENT", default="local")
```

Comment: Версии, что уже означает, что они у меня установлены...

Decouple 0.0.7 - установлен в корень проекта(хотя, лично я ничего нового там не нашел)
Setuptools 68.0.0 - аналогично.
CSV - вообще не врубил, как установить, но это не настолько важно, ибо скорее всего решается быстрее.
Config 0.5.1
Python - 3.7.9 
Unipath 1.1
pathlib2 (он же path) -  2.3.7.post1

Comment: так ты прочитай ошибку. обнови pip и попробуй снова: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: в первую очередь это я и сделал, это не помогло(